# Can I take an internal flight within the US on a UK passport with only four months' validity?

Tags: usa, passports, uk-citizens, domestic-travel

I went to the United States on an ESTA in May and had six months on my passport so was OK to travel. I have now been here two months and therefore have only four months left on my passport.

Can I take an internal flight from Chicago to Grand Rapids or will I have to get my passport renewed?

Answer (score 5):

In principle you shouldn't have to pass through immigration, and therefore the only thing that comes up is if you have valid ID to get on the flight in the first place.

Comment: Note: I've never tried this. Be aware that you never know when officals are going to try and enforce rules.

Comment: In any event there's no rule being broken if the passport has four months' validity remaining.  One can even enter the US with such a passport.